# This variable declaration can creates memory issue

Tags: c

here i have one function which is call many times in one application this application is running continuously.

Here i am take one character array size of 1024.
here i am declaring `char input[1024];`

so which is best way

```
1)    char input[1024];
2)    char input[1024] = NULL;
```

this thing will not create any memory issue after so many times if we used this function.`char input[1024];`

i think may be after using input we have to make NULL ?
or in declaration we have to declare this thing as `char input[1024] = NULL;` so when it will be called next time so that time first input make null than its taking any memory.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void do() {

        char input[1024];

    strcat(input,"ussp-push 04:18:0F:B1:48:B5@9");
    strcat(input,"> dev/null&");

    if(system(input)  != 0)
    {
        printf("\nFailed command\n");
    }
    else
    {
            printf("\nSuccesss command\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: I am surprised this compiles too. When I learnt C, do was a reserved word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program does not initialise `input` at all. This can lead to buffer overrun and even if that does not happen, your program is likely to have incorrect results. Thus your code invokes **undefined behaviour**.

Presumably you actually want to initialize `input` to be an empty string. Like this:

```
char input[1024] = "";
```

Once you have done this your calls to `strcat` will work.

If you don't want to initialise `input` then you can use `strcpy` instead of the first `strcat`:

```
char input[1024];
strcpy(input, "ussp-push 04:18:0F:B1:48:B5@9");
```

If ever you need to assign the empty string to `input` later in the code do it like this:

```
input[0] = '\0';
```

The code you suggest, `char input[1024] = NULL` is not valid. It does not compile.

Comment: I would hope it doesn't compile. Better than trying to copy the first 1024 characters of data from NULL into your buffer.

Comment: okie thanks for your response which is more good char input[1024] = "" or char input[1024];

Comment: @user Which of those is better? They do different things. If you want to initialise input to an empty string use `char input[1024] = ""`. If you don't want to initialise it, don't. You can't compare them like for like because they do different things.

Comment: any one of them will not create any memory issue? if i am using this function more times?

Comment: The code in the question can lead to buffer overrun. It can also lead to erroneous output even if the buffer does not overrun. What exactly do you mean by "memory issue"?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for your reply. Memory issue means any memory allocation problem and any overflow stack memory like that.

Comment: Once you fix the code as I and all the others have described then you won't break the stack. But until you fix the code, it could do just that. Obviously any stack variable could potentially result in a stack overflow. But a plain `char` could do that. So long as you aren't calling this function recursively it's doubtful you would encounter stack overflow on 1024 chars.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7231/discussion-between-user1089679-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: but i am using this function many times after certain interval

Comment: I think you need to learn how local variables work. Every time you call a function, a new local copy of the variable is allocated on the stack.

Comment: Instead of `strcpy` I'd just use `char input[1024] = { "ussp-push 04:18:0F:B1:48:B5@9" };`

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes, but presumably the code in the question is an extract from the real code and the real code does vary the string. If one is going to take your point of view then why bother with a variable. A literal is what you want!

Answer (score 1):

As you're not changing it inside the function, make it a `static const` array

```
void dostuff() {    
    static const char input[] = "ussp-push 04:18:0F:B1:48:B5@9> dev/null&";

    if (system(input) != 0)
    {
        printf("\nFailed command\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nSuccesss command\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't do a reserved word in C?

Comment: @CashCow: oops, yes, `do` is reserved as a keyword. That's what you get when you copy/paste without thinking. Answer edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

strcat appends a string to another, and to do so it searches in the destination string the terminator char (\0). Since you didn't initialize the destination string, it may or may not find the \0 in that.

just initialize it, for example with:

```
input[0]='\0';
```

Comment: ... or replace the 1st `strcat` with a `strcpy`.

Comment: yeah, there are a lot of different ways to do that, even with an `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

This will not compile:

```
char input[1024] = NULL;
```

```
$ make nullarray
cc     nullarray.c   -o nullarray
nullarray.c: In function ‘main’:
nullarray.c:4:2: error: invalid initializer
make: *** [nullarray] Error 1
$
```

When you declare `char input[size]`, the compiler will cause the function prototype to allocate that much memory on the stack (if in a function) or in the `.bss` or `.data` section (if at top-level), and you cannot assign `NULL` to the array to try to stop it.

Perhaps a take step back and describe what problem you're *really* trying to solve? Should you be using `malloc(3)` to allocate memory instead?

Answer (score 0):

This will not cause memory issues. Each time `do()` is called, an array of 1024 bytes will be allocated on the stack; that memory will be used for `input` throughout *that call* of `do()`. When `do()` returns, the 1024 bytes will be freed, and a (conceptually) new set of 1024 will be allocated on the next invocation.

In any case `char input[1024] = NULL;` is not valid code. If you want to initialise `input`, try something like `char input[1024] = "";` instead.

Comment: if i put char input[1024]; directly it will not create problem?

Comment: It will not cause _memory_ problems - you won't run out of memory from repeated calls. You should probably read up on variable scope. As others have posted, your `strcat`s will fail because `input` isn't initialised to a valid string, but that's easily fixed by any of the methods already posted.